# Error: ... is not a package or launch file name

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, ros-groovy, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using ROS groovy and have some packages in my workspace. When I use catkin_make and just want to build one of these packages, I put a CATKIN_IGNORE file into the packages I don't want to be build.

But when I now try to launch one of the packages which have a CATKIN_IGNORE file, roslaunch can't launch and shows "myPackage is not a package or launch file name".

Shouldn't it be possible to launch even if there is a catkin ignore file in the package?

Has anyone experience with catkin_make? Does anyone know how to build just one packet? Any idea how to do this without copying and deleting CATKIN_IGNORE files every time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66508/error:-...-is-not-a-package-or-launch-file-name/) by [Sonne](https://answers.ros.org/users/5074/sonne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sonne](https://answers.ros.org/users/5074/sonne/) on 2013-07-03**:
Thank you. This works fine.

**Comment by [Sonne](https://answers.ros.org/users/5074/sonne/) on 2013-07-05**:
Seems to work fine, if the workspace contains only catkin packages. If there are packages which need to be build with 'catkin_make_isolated' it doesn't work, so that I need to use CATKIN_IGNORE files. Has anyone an idea who to build without putting CATKIN_IGNORE files in the packages in such case?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-07-06**:
By placing a CATKIN_IGNORE file into a package folder you will make this package disappear - not only from the build but also from runtime. You will neither be able to discover the package anymore nor run binaries/launch files from it.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-07-07**:
@Dirk thanks, removing the ignore helped my ROS accepting a roslaunch for a rosbuild package in my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, which had no problems since the last update. But, why has groovy put that file (and lots of folders like devel) in my rosbuild package in the first place without needing them?

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-07-07**:
Nevermind, If I understood [the issue](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rospkg/issues/39) correct, `make eclipse-project` was faulty and responsible for those folders. [related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/66515/update-problem-error-is-not-a-package-or-launch-file-name/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As to building just one package: Use `catkin_make --pkg PACKAGE`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1